# binary search on a single linked list

Tags: c, list, search, hyperlink, binary

How do I perform a binary search on a single linked list headed ? Also it can do it , if there is any particular method. The EP can not tell in advance how many elements of that list , I have to search and enter a cell between q > prox and p .

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is not possible, since binary search requires random access, and a singly-linked list can only provide forward sequential access. Without being able to jump around in memory and look at some `nth` element (either through direct random-access or a skip list), we end up being required to linearly search through the list from beginning to end even if it's sorted.

Comment: I thought so , but the teacher is doing a mystery upon this question , I will use a counter to at least know how many elements have the list and begin the search , because I can not use doubly linked lists . Thanks for help.